# Add a Foreign key relation to existing table using hibernate in spring boot application

Tags: java, database, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I am using hibernate to creating and updating tables. Now i am trying to add relation to a new table from an existing table and i am receiving an error.

**ItemEntity.java**

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Table(name="Item")
@Entity(name="ItemEntity")
public class ItemEntity {

 //item_id

    //item_name

}
```

The above table already have some entries. Now i am trying to add relation between new table(Cart) as a ManyToOne Relationship like below.

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="cart_id", nullable=false)
private Cart cart;
```

**New Entity (CartEntity.java)**

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Table(name="Cart")
@Entity(name="CartEntity")
public class CartEntity {

 //cart_id

 @OneToMany(mappedBy="cart")
 private Set<Items> items;

}
```

As ItemEntity already has some entries in it, i am not able to add the relation like the above. Any help is appreciated. I am getting the below Error when trying to add the relation:

```
org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "alter table Item add constraint F9c5xc7cj5432ua6x332x40 foreign key (item_id) references cart" via JDBC Statement.
```

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: I believe creating a relationship table is acceptable? From DBA's perspective it will look like many-to-many, but in your mapping you can define it such that one side is "one". Something like this although it talks about JPA as well https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-onetomany-association-with-jpa-and-hibernate/